# instead of ng-repeat-start with nested v-for loop in VueJS

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, v-for

So say i have this piece of options code

```
<option ng-repeat-start="item in items" ng-bind="item.name" value="{{item.id}}"></option>
<option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="info in item.info" ng-bind="' - ' + info.name" value="{{info.id}}"></option>
```

So basically option 1 renders and then render all of that items array of info option then next option item will render

but doing this in vue doesn't work

```
<option :key="id" v-for="(item, id) in items" :value="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
<option :key="id" v-for="(info, id) in item" :value="info.name">{{ info.name }}</option>
```

It doesn't see the item in the second v-for as I guess it does the first v-for and the second doesn't know about the first one. How would I achieve the same logic in Vue as I do in Angular?

Comment: could you please share a mock data structure to work with?

Comment: It could be because `v-for="(info, id) in item"` in the second option should be `v-for="(info, id) in item.info" ` like the angular code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could utilize the [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt) tag in vue to loop over an array of objects and child arrays of those objects. and make sure not to duplicate the keys, like the example below:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: function(){
    return {
        selected: null,
      items:[
        {
            name: "Item one in items",
          infos: [
            { 
                name : "info for item one"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
            name: "Item two in items",
          infos: [
            { 
                name : "info for item two"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>Slected: {{selected}}</p>
  <select v-model="selected">
  <template  v-for="(item, itemId) in items" >
    <option :key="itemId" :value="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
    <template  v-for="(info, infoId) in item.infos" >
        <option :key="info.name"  :value="info.name">{{ info.name }}</option>
    </template>
  </template>
  </select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `<option>` should be inside the first `<option>` tag, not after. That’s how nested arrays or objects work in `Vue`. In order to avoid conflict between the `id` in the first and second `<option>`, you should name them differently, for example: `idItem`, `idInfo`